# Read number of lines, words, characters from a file

Tags: c++, boost

I can read the number of lines easy, using:

```
ifstream in(file);
string content;
while(getline(in, content))
{
   // do stuff
}
```

Or I can read the number of words and characters easy using something like:

```
ifstream in(file)
string content;
int numOfCharacters = 0;
int numOfWords = 0;
while(in >> content)
{
   ++numOfWords;
   numOfCharacters += content.size();
}
```

But I dont want to read the file twice. How can I read the file once, and find out the number of lines, words and characters?

PS: I would welcome a Boost sugestion, if there is a easy way.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the line and for each line count the words.  See stringstream for the second part.

(I'm not giving more information, that looks too much like an homework).

Comment: Not homework, just implementing the wc command from linux. You gave me enought information . Thanks.

Comment: Reimplementing wc seems a kind of homework, or at least a kind of exercise you do to learn and for which you'd prefer not to have a complete solution given to you directly.

Comment: I am just making a shell for windows, no big deal, using Boost.Filesystem just to accomodate with this librabry.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with a trivial [boost](http://www.boost.org/).[spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/index.html).[qi](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/quick_start.html) parser.

Answer (score 1):

Sticking with the iostreams solution: you could create a strstream out of each line read via getline(), and do the word/char counting operations on it, accumulating across all the lines.

Comment: Yes, I always forget about stringstream :) Thank you.